# сортировка пузырьком в Ruby

Tags: сортировка, ruby

при запуске кода возникает ошибка : comparison of Integer with nil failed
можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, почему так происходит

```
arr = [1, 4, 2, 7, 5, 8, 3, 9]

   f = arr.length - 1
   for i in 0..f
      for h in 0..f-i
            if arr[h] > arr[h+1]
               arr[h], arr[h+1] = arr[h+1], arr[h]
            
         end
         
      end
   end
  
print arr
```

Comment: Потому что при `i=0` переменная `h` будет хранить в себе индекс последнего элемента массива, а значит `arr[h+1]` выйдет за пределы массива

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in 0..f
  for h in 0..f-i
        if arr[h] > arr[h+1]
```

Когда `i=0`, `h` достигает значения `f`, и `arr[h+1]` обращается к элементу с индексом `arr.length`, которого не существует